# Android wait for AsyncTask to check if server connection is available

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking, networkonmainthread

I want a method which returns the status of internet connectivity, like 'offline' if no connection is available, 'error' if I couldn't connect to the server or 'online' if I'm online without error.

I want to call this method from the main threat, also I couldn't make a HTTP request in the method itself and have to put it in an `AsyncTask` or anything like this. But I don't know how to manipulate my code.

This is nearly what I want, but how could I extract the code in the try block? It always throw the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

```
public static int isOnline(Activity activity)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    int netType = 0;
    if (netInfo != null)
    {
        netType = netInfo.getType();
        if (netInfo.isAvailable() && netInfo.isConnected())
        {
            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            {
                try
                {
                    URL myUrl = new URL(HTTP_HOST);
                    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    connection.connect();
                    return INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_ONLINE;
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    return INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_ERROR;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_OFFLINE;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say that my HTTP_HOST need a HTTP authentication. Maybe I have to add these authentication for the request too?

**EDIT:**

want something like this:

```
public static int isOnline(Activity activity)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    int netType = 0;
    if (netInfo != null)
    {
        netType = netInfo.getType();
        if (netInfo.isAvailable() && netInfo.isConnected())
        {
            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            {
                MyAsyncTask as = new MyAsyncTask();
                return as.execute("") == true ? INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_ONLINE : INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_ERROR;
            }
        }
    }
    return INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY_OFFLINE;
}
```

Comment: "I couldn't make a HTTP request in the method itself and have to put it in an AsyncTask or anything like this" Is your question how do i do http in an async task? Because that's why you're getting the exception.

Comment: What is your host? Try google.com?

Comment: hm, no, I don't know how I could start the `AsyncTask` and WAIT for the result of it to return it in the `isOnline` method.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559991/how-do-i-make-my-connection-an-asynctask-connection

Comment: thank you! But I know how an `AsyncTask` is built on, I only don't know how I could wait for a result of it in my `static` method... sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: By using java's well stocked concurrency library? Ah I get it. You want to know how to wait?

Comment: think I have the solution by using the `task.get(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` method =)

Comment: DO NOT USE GET - it will block the UI thread.  You can use an interface to call back to the starting activity. Clarify your question.

Comment: Agree about not using get btw.

Answer (score 1):

OK- so I think we all misread the question.

Am I right that you want to make a call to the server *before all other calls in your app* to determine if it's available?

Solutions:

1.) Your server could go down at any time. Why not just procede querying the endpoints you *expect* to work and then handle 5xx responses when you need to. This will save you a round trip and greatly enhance stabilty.

2.) Why not use a callback? If you're on the UI thead, ***please*** use a callback. THe *reason* why android thrwos `NetworkOnMainTHread` is because it **blocks** - that means your entire UI will hang. If you use an `AsyncTask` and then block (or "wait" as you say) until it's finished, *you'll only circumnavigate Andorid's inbuilt check*- you'll still have a buggy app were the UI thread hangs.

AsyncTask is designed to make callbacks easy- the method `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thead, while `doInBackground` on a background thread. This is good. Put your code to be executed after your server up check in the `postExecute` bit, do your http in the `doInBackground`.

3.) OK, let's suppose for some reason (which may be perfectly valid ;) ) you need to actually turn your call that starts in an `AsyncTask` into a blocking one?
In that case, you need to override `onPostExecute` in the `AsyncTask` and use a `Semaphore`.

In semi-Java-code:

```
// in your blocking method:
Semaphore myAsyncWaiterSemaphore = new Semaphore(0);
AsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(myAsyncWaiterSemaphore); // take the semaphore in the ctor and set it as a field.
myAsyncWaiterSemaphore.acquire();

// in your async task:
onPostExecute(your-args...) {
    this.mSemaphore.acquire(); // you've passed this in as a field.
}
```

There we go. And then your response would need to have a getter and a setter for the response code somewhere to check the result.

But please don't do (3) unless you're sure you need it. Yes, (3) is how you wait for an async load of http to finish if you want to do it in a blocking method, but still much better to use callbacks and fire off the rest of your app's http once that first callback is fired.

I realise this is a lot to think about, so please do post comments so I can clarify.

Best.

Comment: I call the `isOnline` methode often, e.g. before showing the online/offline Icon in ActionBar. If I'm online (and server is available) I start an `AsyncTask` to download new data. Because of that I want to have a central method which says: you're online and server is available. User shouldn't notice, when I look for this. Is the `myAsyncTask.get(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` no good option? Don't misunderstand me: It's ONLY for `isOnline` to recognize server availability, when I normally use `AsyncTasks` I show the user a `ProgressDialog`. Maybe I should test your option 3.

Comment: Now that you tell me more information, whilst it's up to you to decide on your design, sounds to me like you actually need something called a "latch". Basically, in your method where your "AsyncTask to download new data" (and whatever else you like) gets fired, you wait on a latch (like a `CountdownLatch`, for example) which blocks before you fire that later task. Then, on your UI thread, you start an AsyncTask to check for your server's availability. In the `postExecute` of that, get a reference to that latch and count it down. Then, as if by magic, all your other tasks will fire off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this whevered you want just make your own InternetDetector or whatever else you want to call it class:

```
public class InternetDetector{

    private InternetDetector(){ }

    public static InternetDetector getInstance(){
        return new InternetDetector();
    }

    public boolean isOnline(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        int netType = 0;
        if (netInfo != null){
            netType = netInfo.getType();
            if (netInfo.isAvailable() && netInfo.isConnected()){
                if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || netType ==       ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

}

Once you create this class you can call it from anywhere. Just use the static factory to get an instance and check availability.

```
    if(InternetDetector.getInstance().isOnline()){
          //do your internt stuff here
    }
```

You can execute any code that needs the internet in this if statment since, if its true, there's an internet out there.

Comment: but this only looks for Internetconnectivity NOT if the server is available

Answer (score 0):

Watch this: Google I/O 2010 - Android REST client applications https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

And read this: http://blog.ericwoodruff.me/2013/09/android-remote-sync-content-provider.html

Summary: You shouldn't be doing any downloading from an AsyncTask. This should be done in an IntentService or, better, in a SyncAdatper with a ContentProvider.